# Generate vtt file automatically

Tags: database, jwplayer, webvtt

How can I generate vtt file automatically. How can I get beginning and end-time of each chapter from `video_table` in database and generate `vtt` but not manually.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: WEBVTT

Chapter 1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:50.000
Seminar ProIdeen

Chapter 2
00:00:50.000 --> 00:02:41.000
Vorlesungsangebot in Deutsch    --> this is my vtt file. instead of giving Cue timings manually, i want to read them from my database. so whenever I insert a new chapter to my video_table in database, so the Cue timings and Chapter title will be genarated automatically